Where is the corridor?
The question asks us to find where the coffee room is.
Do you think it is clear that the red corridor is the corridor that the speaker is talking about? The speaker doesn't say where we're facing so I think it's possible that the speaker is talking about the blue corridor. Or the blue area can't be called a corridor? Although the last sentence makes it clear that H is the coffee room. But I want to ask if the bold part clearly tells listeners where the corridor is.

We're in the reception area, which we try to make attractive and
welcoming to visitors. There's a corridor running left from here,
and if you go along that, the door facing you at the end is the
entrance to the coffee room. This looks out onto the main road on one
side, and some trees on the other, and that'll be where you meet each
morning. (Source: my Cambridge book)



Yes, if the speaker is asking listeners to refer to the plan. No, otherwise.

Why? Because the red area is longer and narrower than the blue area?

Because the red area is to the left of RECEPTION on the plan that you have shown. The blue one is above RECEPTION. <----- LEFT,   RIGHT ---->

Also, only the red corridor leads directly to the door of a room facing both the trees and the main road.

Thank you both but @MichaelHarvey, the speaker only says we are in the reception area. We may be in the reception area and facing J and not G.

@newbieforever - indeed, and that is the reason for my first comment. This looks like a comprehension or logical thinking test applying to the text and plan viewed together.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not an English language question.

If you walk into the corridor from reception, you'll be facing northwest (if north is up). Then the closest thing to left is indeed the red corridor. Likewise, when you enter the building, the red corridor is to the left. With a puzzle like this, you need to use some common sense: if someone points up a road and says "take the second road on the left", do you ask them "whose left?" or say "Ah but it wouldn't be left if I was coming from the other direction"?

This would be the same thing in your language, if it isn't English.

Logically, room H has to be the coffee room, because if you take the corridor from reception the only door "facing you" is the door to room H. If you take the turn and continue along the corridor past rooms F,D and E you come to a wall and there are only doors off the left or right.
There are a couple of things about this that could be confusing. Firstly, it begins by saying the corridor 'runs left' from the reception. Directions like left and right are relative - for example, if you were facing me, my left would be your right - so the direction on the map may not be the direction you would actually take. However, the outer door into the reception as shown on the map is located so that, as you walk into the reception, the door to the corridor is indeed off to the left. I can almost forgive this ambiguity. But 'reception' in a functional building can refer to the reception desk where you are greeted, and the map doesn't show us where such a desk, if any, is located. If it were anywhere but straight ahead of you as you enter from outside an instruction to "go left from reception" would be very confusing indeed.
What is less clear is the instruction to "go along" the corridor to "the end". Arguably the corridor takes a right turn and the 'end' is where rooms A and B are. A better, less ambiguous instruction would be to "take the corridor and the door straight ahead is the coffee room". However, as I said at the start of my answer, having the map means you can deduct using logic which the room is.
The area you highlighted in blue does not meet the definition of a corridor which is "a long passage". Some might call it a 'passage', but it doesn't look long enough to even be called that, in my opinion. An "alcove" or a "nook", perhaps? It looks just about big enough for a door to open into, so I wouldn't even consider it worthy of being called anything.

Thanks for the answer. Can the blue area be called a corridor though? According to the dictionary, a corridor is a long passage. So I'm not sure if that short blue area can be called a corridor

@newbieforever added a paragraph about that for you.
